# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Przychody#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

sorry if this was asked before. I was looking for my problem, but I couldn't find the exact solution or I didn't understand it. I am pretty new to RoR or programing  in general. I follow the tutorial on this site: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. 
I got stuck on step 5.2 at the: url part. I think there is something wrong with my routing because that's the message of my error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"przychody"}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :przychody

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Here is my new.html.erb file:

```
<h1>Nowy Przychód</h1>

<%= form_with scope: :przychod, url: przychody_path, local: true do |przychod| %>
  <p>
    <%= przychod.label :tytuł %><br>
    <%= przychod.text_field :tytuł %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= przychod.label :treść %><br>
    <%= przychod.text_area :treść %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= przychod.label :kwota %><br>
    <%= przychod.number_field :kwota %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= przychod.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Here is what my rake routes shows:

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                        welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)                                                                 welcome#index
                      przychody_index GET    /przychody(.:format)                                                                     przychody#index
                                      POST   /przychody(.:format)                                                                     przychody#create
                        new_przychody GET    /przychody/new(.:format)                                                                 przychody#new
                       edit_przychody GET    /przychody/:id/edit(.:format)                                                            przychody#edit
                            przychody GET    /przychody/:id(.:format)                                                                 przychody#show
                                      PATCH  /przychody/:id(.:format)                                                                 przychody#update
                                      PUT    /przychody/:id(.:format)                                                                 przychody#update
                                      DELETE /przychody/:id(.:format)                                                                 przychody#destroy
                                 root GET    /                                                                                        welcome#index
```

I would be really grateful if someone could explain to me what is wrong, show me the answer or give me the link to the post with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to **url: przychody_path**, as you seen in rake routes, this will expect **id** value.

```
<%= form_with scope: :przychod, url: przychody_path, local: true do |przychod| %>
```

Try to use

```
<%= form_with scope: :przychod, url: "/przychody", local: true do |przychod| %>
```